# Dart without Dart-Editor: Refreshing

Tags: dart, dart-pub

I'm trying to program in Dart but without the Dart-Editor. It works fine so far but its really annoying and slow to always call pub build after making a change to either html/css or dart code.

As far as I remember when launching the app with Dart-Editor you just have to refresh the page.

Is it possible to get this working without the editor?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `pub serve` which is similar to the webserver integrated in the Darteditor.
If you are using Dartium as browser you can add `--no-dart2js` so `pub serve` doesn`t generate JavaScript (which is slow) but directly serves Dart which Dartium can process directly.

For other browsers it's of course convenient to use the integrated dart2js conversion.

Comment: that's what I was looking for! I really should read through ALL of the pub doc - thank you